# stopping onclick from redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a javascript function that is called when a link is clicked. However I just want the function to run without the link redirecting. I have heard I should use return false but it doesn't work!

```
function hideaddclasses(e){
var element = document.getElementById("addclasses");
if(element.style.display=="none"){
    element.style.display="";
}else{
    element.style.display="none";
}
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
```

Then for the html I simply have:

```
<a href='#' onclick='hideaddclasses()'>[ Hide ]</a>
```

Why does it still redirect?

Comment: The return false; may have to be in the "onclick" itself: onclick='hideaddclasses(); return false;'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<a href='#' onclick='return hideaddclasses()'>[ Hide ]</a>
```

*(Note the `return`)*.

Comment: Why do I need to do this for everyone one.. so annoying?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `e.preventDefault()`